# Vertically center text in container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/gomwyt2j/1/

Super simple, I just need to center the text vertically so it lines up with the button

Nothing I try seems to work

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center text"><p>Some Info</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center text"><p>Some more Info Her</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center btn-btn"><a class="btn">Read More</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center text"><p>Some Info</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center text"><p>Some more Info Her</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><a class="btn">Read More</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `line: height`:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center text">
            <p>Some Info</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center text">
            <p>Some more Info Her</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center btn-btn"><a class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center text">
            <p>Some Info</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center text">
            <p>Some more Info Her</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"><a class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.row {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.text p {
    display: inline-block;
    //padding: 9px 0 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-btn {
}
.btn {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-sm-3, .col-sm-4 {
    line-height: 35px; /*add line height*/
}
p {
    margin: 0;/*remove margin from p*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gomwyt2j/2/)